# Trying to post JSON using AJAX and receiving 400's

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm sending an AJAX request to a Tomcat 7 server and I keep getting 'Bad Request' responses back. I have been debugging in both NetBeans and Eclipse with Chrome and FireFox. The request does not appear to be getting to the web application. I have captured and validated the JSON using two different web tools and double checked all the variable names with the Request objects being created. I'm new to debugging Tomcat and would really appreciate any assistance. My javascript code is below:

```
function submitScoring(selected, dataSource) {
    if (!validate()) {
        alert("Please complete the highlighted fields.");
        return false;
    }

    var documents = getDocuments($("#table-available").dataTable(), selected);

    var request = {
        "database": dataSource,
        "userName": $("#userName").val(),
        "modelName": $("#modelName").val(),
        "documents": documents
    };

    sendRequest(request, "scoring");
}

function getDocuments(srcTable, areSelected) {
    var documents = new Array();

    if (areSelected) {
        srcTable.$("tr.selected").each(function () {
            documents.push(getDocument(this));
        });
    } else {
        srcTable.$("tr").each(function () {
            documents.push(getDocument(this));
        });
    }
    return documents;
}

function getDocument(row) {
    return {
        "metadata": {
            "id": row.cells[0].textContent,
            "title": row.cells[1].textContent,
            "language": row.cells[2].textContent,
            "format": row.cells[3].textContent
        },
        "lastUpdated": row.cells[4].textContent,
        "documentUri": row.cells[5].textContent
    };
}

function sendRequest(request, type) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(request);

    $.ajax({
        url: $appRoot + "/submit/" + type,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: json,
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            alert("Your " + type + " job request was submitted successfully.");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('request failed ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: Spring MVC is involved also and the excerpted code from the Controller is below:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/scoring", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> submitDocsToScore(@RequestBody ScoringRequest jsonRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws InvalidFormatException, AccumuloException, AccumuloSecurityException, IOException, TableNotFoundException, Docx4JException,
        ShutdownSignalException, ConsumerCancelledException, InterruptedException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException {

    ralInterface.makeRequest(jsonRequest);

    return new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

EDIT 2: I stated earlier that I've double checked this already, but let me post the relevant code here also:

```
public abstract class Request { 
    protected String database; 
    protected String userName; 
    protected String modelName; 
    // getters and setters follow 
}

public class ScoringRequest extends Request { 
    private List<Document> documents; 
    // getters and setters follow 
}

public class Document implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, String> metadata;
    private String documentUri;
    private Date lastUpdated;
    // getters and setters follow
}
```

Comment: I feel there is a conflict with `Date lastUpdated` field!

Comment: That was it exactly. I modified the javascript to create a Date object from the text and it worked fine. Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Comment: Sorry, I thought of putting a detailed answer but got stuck with my work. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sudhansu Choudhary pointed out I needed to use an actual Date object and not a String when returning from the getDocument funtion.